# Namespace handling in Groovys XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, parsing, grails, groovy, xmlslurper

The situation:

```
def str = """
  <foo xmlns:weird="http://localhost/">
    <bar>sudo </bar>
    <weird:bar>make me a sandwich!</weird:bar>
  </foo>
"""
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(str)
println xml.bar
```

The output of this snippet is

```
# sudo make me a sandwich!
```

It seems like the parser merges the contents of `<bar>` and `<weird:bar>`.

Is this behavior desired and if yes, how can I avoid this and select only `<bar>` or `<weird:bar>`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default XMLSlurper is not namespace aware. This can be turned on by declaring namespaces with the `declareNamespace` [Method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#declareNamespace%28java.util.Map%29).

```
def str = """ 
<foo xmlns:weird="http://localhost/">
  <bar>sudo </bar>
  <weird:bar>make me a sandwich!</weird:bar>
</foo>
""" 
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(str).declareNamespace('weird':'http://localhost/')
println xml.bar // without namespace awareness, will print "sudo make me a sandwich!"
println xml.':bar' // will only print "sudo"
println xml.'weird:bar' // will only print "make me a sandwich!"
```

The output is:

```
sudo make me a sandwich!
sudo
make me a sandwich!
```

The first `println` will still not be namespace aware. The second `println` will only print the tag without namespace. If you qualify element with the prefix shown in the third `println` you only get the namespaced tag.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a few things :) I'm parsing different xmls and I do not know which namespaces they are using; is there any possibility to achieve the output of `println xml.':bar'` apart from parsing the root element for namespaces and declaring them?

Comment: I think that XmlSlurper is namespace aware by default, since `new XmlSlurper() -> new XmlSlurper(false, true)`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418826/are-xmlparser-and-xmlslurper-namespace-aware-by-default

Comment: Ugh.  For some reason, this isn't working for me.  I'm parsing an RSS document with namespaces declared in the headers.  I can access rss.channel.link but rss.channel.'atom:link'.text() and rss.channel.'atom:link'.@href.text() all return blank values.  :(

Comment: I fixed it with .declareNamespace('atom':'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom').   But argh, why should I have to do this when the header is in the xmlns element in the response?

Answer (score 4):

I know this was answered a while ago, but here's an alternative for anyone else facing the same issue. The `XmlSlurper` class has three constructors, [a couple of which](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#XmlSlurper-boolean-boolean-) allow you to specify you want it to be namespace-aware.

```
public XmlSlurper(boolean validating, boolean namespaceAware)
```

Declare the slurper by calling `new XmlSlurper(false, true)`.
I hope this is useful to others.