# Making simple xml file from soap Request in nifi

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, apache-nifi

I have read  that TransformXml  processor can convert  other  files  to regular xml.  i need  to convert my soap response into  xml file  should  i use TransformXml or should i make it via  groovy code?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem correct. Do you have any sample input and output data which you want transfrom?

Comment: Yes  i  have  soap  response  with related  data  and i want to write  it  in simple xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, I'm not sure which is faster from a performance perspective. If you have an XSLT that will extract your SOAP response as XML (there are examples here on StackOverflow), then use TransformXML. Otherwise you can use Groovy in ExecuteScript, just make sure to make the slurper is [namespace-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669766/namespace-handling-in-groovys-xmlslurper).