# how to modify couple of values in a xml file using groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

Below is my xml saved in a file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag0:Document xmlns:tag0="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.05">
   <tag0:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
      <tag0:GrpHdr>
         <tag0:MsgId>**ffa509ddaa7e450a832f0c5ce417f320**</tag0:MsgId>
         <tag0:CreDtTm>2023-01-04T16:06:09.758Z</tag0:CreDtTm>
         <tag0:NbOfTxs>1</tag0:NbOfTxs>
         <tag0:InitgPty>
            <tag0:Nm>TTCB</tag0:Nm>
         </tag0:InitgPty>
      </tag0:GrpHdr>
   </tag0:CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
</tag0:Document>
```

I would like to change the value of inside  tag0:MsgId , each time I run my test case.
How can I modify this value using groovy?

I tried below code:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse("C:\\Users\\indrani\\Desktop\\test\\OneDrive_1_9-13-2023\\pain001_wire_ach.xml")
xml.CstmrCdtTrfInitn.GrpHdr.MsgId = "1234567890"
def writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\indrani\\Desktop\\test\\OneDrive_1_9-13-2023\\pain001_wire_ach.xml")
XmlUtil.serialize(xml, writer)
writer.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Namespace handling in Groovys XmlSlurper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669766/namespace-handling-in-groovys-xmlslurper)